# Android location listener does not work on some devices

Tags: android, locationlistener

I need to find user location in android. As I do not want to use GPS, I tried below code to find user location based on his/her Network, this works on some devices but not on all of them, what is the problem? is it becuase of Android version or something like hardware issues?

```
private double x, y;
private LocationManager lm;
lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, locationListenerNetwork);


LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        x = location.getLatitude();
        y = location.getLongitude();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
give latitude and longitude in FetchLocationTask class

```
    latitude = 27.003434;
    longitude = 23.458569;
    new FetchLocationTask(getActivity(), latitude, longitude).execute();



    public class FetchLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            public Context context;
            // private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            public String addressUrl;
            public BufferedReader in;

            public FetchLocationTask(Context context, double lat, double longi) {
                this.context = context;
                addressUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + longi + "&sensor=true";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            /**
             * Call the webservice and parse the data from the service in
             * background.
             */
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();// Client

                    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
                    getRequest.setURI(new URI(addressUrl));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    String page = sb.toString();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);

                    if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results");

                        if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                            jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
                            if (jsonObject.has("formatted_address")) {
                                address = (String) jsonObject.get("formatted_address");
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    return null;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * onPostExecute method after called webService and Set the data into
             * adapter after background task is complete.
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                if (address != null && address.length() > 0) {

                    Log.i("map", "My:::" + address);
                    etx_address.setText(address.toString());

                }
            }
        }
```